# Asian option equation

Tags: asian-option

Im trying to find an equation for the discrete geometric asian option put price and are seeing a lot of differencies. Any recommondations for good papers??
I also tried to proof the call price from the picture but im facing a lot of difficulties. Can anybody give me a Hint that may help me?
I would appreciate every help i could get [image: call price]

Comment: Please, add reference of your equation, list of research papers you look and details of your difficulty in implementation.